# Finding path using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

Here's the problem

Provided that we have a nxn square board with each small square inside contains either 1 or 0. Start at the upper left square (0,0), find the path to the lowest square to the right (n,n) that yield the largest binery number made from all the square it pass.

```
**Input**
first line: n.  
the following n lines : each line contains n numbers of 0 or 1.  

**Output**
the decimal number of the largest binary string you found.
```

And here is my code. i use recursion to find all path that moves to the last square and with each path i generate a binary string and put them into a vector. At the end i will print the largest number in the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
#define rep(I,N) for(int I=0;I<(N);++I)
int n;
char field[100][100];
vector<string>bin;
vector<int>de;
string tmp;

int dec(string bin)
{
    int d=0;
    for (int i = bin.size() - 1;i >= 0;--i)
        if (bin[i] == '1')d += pow(2, i);
    return d;
}

void path(int x = 0,int y = 0)
{

    if(x>n-1||y>n-1)
    return;
    else if(x==n-1&&y==n-1)
    {
        tmp.push_back(field[x][y]);
        reverse(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
        de.push_back(dec(tmp));
        tmp.clear();
    }
    else
    {
        tmp.push_back(field[x][y]);
        path(x + 1, y);
        path(x, y + 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    cin >> n;
    rep(i,n)rep(j,n)
        cin >> field[i][j];
    path();
    cout << *max_element(de.begin(), de.end());
    return 0;   
}
```

The sample test i got from my teacher is

```
5 

-1 -0 -1  1  0    
0  0 -1  0  1  
0  0 -1  0  1  
1  0 -0 -1  1  
1  1  0 -1 -0
```

Which should print 374 which is 101110010 (the path that i marked from the test) but when i use it on my code it print 314 like this path.

```
-1  0  1  1  0    
-0  0  1  0  1  
-0  0  1  0  1  
-1  0  0  1  1  
-1 -1 -0 -1 -0
```

I tried debugging, it seems to be able to find only some of the paths, but i cant identify the exact problem. Can someone teels me what's wrong with my code and how to fix it, thank you very much.

Comment: I would prefer `1 << i` to `pow(2, i)` because I think floating-point aritimetic may contain errors.

Comment: I wrote a somewhat similar shifting tile puzzle solver [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf164639becd94c1) that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the path at the goal will prevent searching for path branched from the middle of the path. You should use `pop_back` to get back.

Try this:

```
void path(int x = 0,int y = 0)
{

    if(x>n-1||y>n-1)
    return;
    else if(x==n-1&&y==n-1)
    {
        tmp.push_back(field[x][y]);
        reverse(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
        de.push_back(dec(tmp));
        reverse(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
        tmp.pop_back();
    }
    else
    {
        tmp.push_back(field[x][y]);
        path(x + 1, y);
        path(x, y + 1);
        tmp.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Note that what is reversed has to be reversed again in order to make the path after returning correct.